# Problem with get access to a variable in json string when use mysql and ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I have some problem with jquery. Why there is a problem accessing a variable in the json string?

```
$(function() {
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    data: {
      test: "test"
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response); // {"login":"1","status_":0,"user":1}
      console.log(response.login); //undefined
      test = JSON.parse(response); // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 2
      console.log(test.login); //not work 
    },
    complete: function(response) {
    }
  });
})();
```

```
test.php
require("config.php");
require("dbconnect.php");
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $_POST["login"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$user = $sth->fetch();
if(@$user['email']==$_POST["test"]) { 
$json = json_encode(array("login" =>"1","status_"=>0, "user" => 1), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
else { 
$json = json_encode(array("login" =>"1", "status_"=>1, "user" => 1), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
}
echo $json;
```

This is a small php script that returns a single JSON string by simple condition.

If I not use code below:

```
require("config.php");
require("dbconnect.php");
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $_POST["test"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$user = $sth->fetch();
```

it works and console.log(response.login)//return 1), but if I use a database connection, it doesn't. Why?

Comment: It would seem you have an illegal character in your JSON. Can you share the PHP that generates it?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `$()` doesn't create an IIFE, you don't need `()` after it.

Comment: I see no problem in JSON when I print `console.log(response.login)`. The JSON is valid. Are you sure ` {"login":"1","status_":0,"user":1}` is the exact JSON you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `dataType` in your Ajax call. like -

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Or parse your string to a valid JSON. like

```
JSON.parse(response);
```

The second thing you should normally encode your JSON on the server end. See -

```
$json = json_encode(array("login" =>"1", "status_"=>1, "user" => 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an require config.php in dbconnect.php and script work normal, but this is an some kind of anomaly probably.